# Cat command with a csv file

Tags: regex, cat

I have a file called "polls.csv" that I have to use the cat command to return a certain part of. Each line of the file looks like this:
Utah,5,27,64,4,Sep 13,,,,,,,5,American Res. Group

Here is an example of the cat output: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4WRI.png

How could I run a cat command and only return the polling organization, "American Res. Group" in the example line, for each line. 
I'm assuming it would look similar to:
cat polls.csv /^[]$/

Also how could I have it count a total of the amount of different polling organizations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `cat` command will do the job alone. I guess you should have a look at gnu core utils package where you will find a lot of tools: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/index.html

One simple way of doing it is:

```
cat polls.csv |sed -s "s/.*,//"
```

sed -s "s/.*,//" replaces everything before last comma with nothing, hence leaving polling organisation.

For your second question, you can continue to use `sort -u` which will sort everthing uniquely and then do `wc -l` to count, for example:

```
cat polls.csv|sed -s "s/.*,//"|sort -u|wc -l
```

---

For consonant check, it is a separate problem definition. There are many ways to check it. Here's my way on top of my head:

```
# /bin/python
import sys
import re

consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"

def count_consonants(word):
    count = 0
    for x in word:
        if x in consonants:
            count += 1
    return count

while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if line:
        line = line.rstrip()
        line = re.sub(" +", " ", line)
        words = line.split(" ")
        for w in words:
            c = count_consonants(w)
            if c >= 6:
                print w
    else:
        break
```

Please save it as `script.py` and Then do it:

```
cat polls.csv|sed -s "s/.*,//"|sort -u|python script.py
```

or

```
cat words|python script.py
```

Comment: Could you help me with something else? I have a file named words that is a list of a bunch of different words. How could I output all of the words that have six (or more) consonants (non-vowels) in a row.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I misunderstood your requirement. try this:

```
awk -F, '{print $NF}' polls.csv
```